# How to convert a function that accept multiple parameters into a predicate?

Tags: clojure

I see the following code on the [Clojure wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/API_Examples/Predicate_functions)

```
user=> (filter nil? [:a :b nil nil :a]) 
(nil nil)
```

and I see `nil?` is a predicate.
However, I currently want to convert `clojure.contrib.string/substring?` into a predicate, which means, although `substring` is a function that accepts two parameters, I want to set the first one as fixed.
How can I do that?

Currently I'm doing this by writing something like this

```
(filter (fn [x] (clojure.contrib.string/substring? "todo" x))
        ["todo" "todo" nil "todos"])
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is fine except

- `clojure.contrib.string` has been absorbed into `clojure.string` and `substring?` is no more. See [clojure.contrib migration](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go).
- You need protection from the `nil`s in your sample data.

You can also use the `#()` reader macro if you like, for example with regular expressions

```
(filter #(when % (re-find #"todo" %)) ["todo" "todo" nil "todos"])
```

or Java interop

```
(filter #(when % (.contains % "todo")) ["todo" "todo" nil "todos"])
```

both

```
;=> ("todo" "todo" "todos")
```